# Hide password using expect script

Tags: bash, expect

I used the script to log into the power broker and connected
ssh through the network. As per my knowledge every single more is 
tracked. I am ok with that.

My question is how to hide the password, below sample I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout 2
spawn pbrun /bin/su - big_admin
expect {
       "Password for casper@BIG_BANK.COM:" {send "foobar_pass!\r" ; exp_continue }
        "*$*" ;
}
interact
```

I tried storing my password in a `/home/casper/.password` and then doing a chmod 400 on it and then 
putting it in the `{send "/home/casper/.password\r" exp continue}`, but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source  : http://wiki.tcl.tk/3594

**Procedure to encrypt device passwords**

- Takes pd (password list to be encrypted) and filename (name of file for resulting encrypted password list) as input
- Returns nothing
- Format of the list of passwords (current and older generations by device type?) depends on how calling program needs them - suggest separated by \n character for readability

`proc utility_encrypt {pd filename} {
    global key HOME
    #catch [exec echo "$pd" | des -e -k $key -b > $HOME/pwdir/$filename]
    catch [exec des -e -k $key -b > [file join $HOME pwdir $filename] << $pd]
    return
}`

**Procedure to decrypt device passwords**

- Takes filename (name of password file to decrypt)
- Returns dpd (list of passwords in plaintext)

`proc utility_decrypt filename {
            global key HOME
            catch {exec cat $HOME/pwdir/$filename | des -d -b -k $key} dpd
                # Some people write the previous command as
            # catch {exec des -d -b -k $key < $HOME/pwdir/$filename} dpd
            return $dpd
     }`